# d3 retrieve and add to current selection's attribute value

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to get the values for an element's translation.

For example, if I select the x axis:

`d3.select('.x.axis').attr("transform")`

then I get

`"translate(0,112)"`

How do I get the `0` and the `112` without parsing a regexp?

I'm trying to do it so that I can add to the value.  In pseudocode:

```
d3.selectAll('.x.axis').attr('transform', 'translate('
        .attr('transform').match(/(\d+)(\.\d+)?/g)[0] // <-- clearly won't work
        + additional_value
        + ', 0)');
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

D3 provides the [`transform()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Math#wiki-transform) for exactly this purpose:

```
var t = d3.transform(d3.select('.x.axis').attr("transform")),
    x = t.translate[0],
    y = t.translate[1];
```

Comment: How would I go about doing it with a selectAll?  So that I'm iterating on each element and, say, storing the x & y in an array?

Comment: You could use `.each()`, which calls the function argument for each element in the selection.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying (in the Chrome console) but am having issues with scope.  That is, `.attr` works on the d3 selection but I can't seem to get access to it -- from the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each) I only get the datum (d) the index (i) and the current DOM selection (this).

Comment: You can get access to the current element through `d3.select(this)`.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not getting the values that I expect.  Specifically, I'm getting [0,0] although I see that there is a non zero x value in the transform attribute when I inspect the DOM element.

Comment: Could you post an example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: My bad, nevermind.  I thought that the `.attr("transform")` part of your answer wasn't necessary because that's what the `d3.transform` part did.  Turns out it's essential although I'm not sure why.. Alls good!

Comment: `d3.transform` only parses the string, it doesn't retrieve it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the simplest solution I found and it works perfectly!

Comment: only available in **v3** , not d3.js v4 - https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/API-Reference.md

Comment: For d3.js v4, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38230545/1703772 and send in the transform attribute directly.

Answer (score 4):

if you would like to use selectAll you could try something like this:

```
// move ticks to the center of the x-axis   
var transform;
d3.selectAll('.tick').attr('transform', function(){
  transform = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform"));
  return "translate("+transform.translate[0]+", -3)";
});
```

Comment: The code illustrates how you could solve the problem of using translate with d3.selectAll. to operate on multiple elements. in the comments above ari gold asked how to do this. the code is selecting all the elements that have the class '.tick'. getting the transform attribute and running a function to set the transform attribute. that function uses d3.transform to get values so you could update it in place.