# Error: d3.transform is not a function

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to get an element's coordinates using:

```
var _blurblur = d3.transform(d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('transform')).translate;
```

But I got an error:

> d3.transform is not a function

What have I missed?

Comment: I hope you are using d3 v4 d3.transfom is not present in v4 version ...please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224875/replacing-d3-transform-in-d3-v4