# d3 4.6 equivalent code for d3.transform

Tags: d3.js

I am in the process of upgrading my code to use d3.js 4.6.

I have the following old code which is erroring:

```
const findZeroTick = (data) => {
  return data === 0.0;
}

const y = graphContainer.selectAll(".y.axis .tick").filter(findZeroTick)
                                .map((tick) => {
                                  return d3.transform(select(tick[0]).attr('transform')).translate[1];-
                                })[0];
```

SelectAll no longer returns what I expect and `d3.transform` has been removed.

What is an equivalent in the new regime for `d3.transform`?

Comment: Please advise the code to initiate the object 'graphContainer'?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38230545/5768908