# consolidate successive translations in D3

Tags: d3.js, svg, iteration, translation

The following toy code ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/16365/)) write to the console log  `translate(20,0) translate(20,0) translate(20,0) translate(20,0) translate(20,0)`. 
Is it possible to get `translate(100,0)` as a "consolidated" translation?

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var rec=svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width",20)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .attr("fill","#00ffff")
    .attr("transform","")
    ;
   for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
   rec
   .attr("transform",rec.attr("transform")+" translate(20,0)")
   ;
   }
   console.log(rec.attr("transform"))
```

Comment: Um, `20 * 5`?  `rec.attr("transform",rec.attr("transform")+" translate(" + (20 * 5) + ",0)");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I believe you want to get `translate(200,0)` as the result, not `translate(100,0)`, since there are 10 loops.

That being said, you have to get the translate values and add `20` to the first one and `0` to the second one. Otherwise you'll just concatenate strings, as you are doing right now.

Unfortunately there is no native method in D3 v4/v5 to get the transform value, so I'll use the function provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38230545/5768908), with a slight modification (the `if` conditional), since your first value is an empty string (`""`):

```
function getTranslation(transform) {
  if (transform === "") {
    return [0, 0]
  };
  var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
  g.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", transform);
  var matrix = g.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;
  return [matrix.e, matrix.f];
}
```

So, all you need is to get the current translate and add the value you want in your `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var currentTransform = getTranslation(rec.attr("transform"));
  rec.attr("transform", "translate(" + (currentTransform[0] + 20) + ",0)");
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var rec = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .attr("fill", "#00ffff")
  .attr("transform", "");

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var currentTransform = getTranslation(rec.attr("transform"));
  rec.attr("transform", "translate(" + (currentTransform[0] + 20) + ",0)");
}

console.log(rec.attr("transform"))

function getTranslation(transform) {
  if (transform === "") {
    return [0, 0]
  };
  var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
  g.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", transform);
  var matrix = g.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;
  return [matrix.e, matrix.f];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```