# Scale a path object after translating

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've set up some code to take a path and scale and move, however it appears that once a new transform is inplace, the old one is removed? How can I move and scale a path?

```
var path = svg.append('path')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
        var x = 100, y = 100;
        return path;
    })
    .style("fill", "#1a5d18")
    .attr("transform", "translate(300,0)");

var path = path.attr("transform","scale(.3)");
```

Comment: `.attr("transform", "translate(300,0) scale(.3)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already know, setting the new `transform` will override the previous one.

Let's see this in this basic demo:

```js
const circle = d3.select("circle");
circle.attr("transform", "translate(100,50)");
circle.attr("transform","scale(.3)");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle r="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

As you can see (actually, you *cannot* see!), we move the circle to `100,50`, but the `scale(0.3)` makes the circle going back to its original position.

A possible solution is getting the previous `transform` value. Unfortunately, D3 v4 and v5 don't have `d3.transform` anymore, but it can be replaced, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38230545/5768908).

However, *in your specific case*, you can get the previous `translate` value using [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) directly in the DOM element, and adding the `scale`.

Here is the demo:

```js
const circle = d3.select("circle");
circle.attr("transform", "translate(100,50)");
circle.attr("transform", function() {
  return this.getAttribute("transform") +
    " scale(0.3)";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle r="50"></circle>
</svg>
```