# Get attribute x for axis' text element

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I created an XAXIS using d3.axisBottom(). Now I need to store the positions (x and y attributes of the tick text) in a separate variable.

My full code is at codepen
https://codepen.io/zubair57/pen/gOLeeOm

When I use below code to get "x and y" attributes, I get value for y attr but null for x attr. Could you tell me why I get null for x attr and how to get correct value

```
d3.select(".xaxis").selectAll(".tick text").each(function(d,i){
    let me=d3.select(this)  
    console.log(me.attr("x"))
    console.log(me.attr("y"))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D3 the axis generator creates several groups translated along the x axis (in the case of `d3.axisBottom()`), and then the texts have only the `y` position set. For instance, in your axis:

```
<g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(50.5,0)">
<!-- x translated here ---------------------------^  -->
    <line stroke="currentColor" y2="0" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 2;"></line>
    <text fill="currentColor" y="3" dy="0.71em" style="fill: black; font-size: 20px; font-family: Arial;">1</text>
</g>
etc...
```

Therefore, there is no `x` attribute to get.

For getting the `x` position of the text you have to select their parents, which are `this.parentNode`. However, using methods like `getBBox()` won't work because the element is translated. You could use `d3.transform()` in v3, but it was removed in D3 v4 and above. For a workaround, please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38230545/5768908