# D3 v4 Get translate values of an element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When I run `d3.select(this).attr("transform")` on an element, I get a response `translate(20.00,778)`. However I need to get individual values of translate.

In v3, one can use

```
var t = d3.transform(element.attr("transform"));
t.translate;
```

However [d3.transform](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Math.md#d3_transform) is not available in v4. How to achieve an equivalent result?

Comment: You can achieve it by creating your own function. THis answer shows how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38230545/5768908

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340263/d3-retrieve-and-add-to-current-selections-attribute-value

Answer (score 8):

Try this.

```
string = element.attr("transform");

translate = string.substring(string.indexOf("(")+1, string.indexOf(")")).split(",");
```

Then you can access dx by translate[0] and dy by translate[1].

Comment: Although it would be clean to use D3 function, this helps for the time being

Comment: This doesn't work for in Edge as edge does separate the arguments with whitespace such as translate(10 20) instead of translate(10,20) like chrome and firefox.